# Liferay Logout.events.pre doesn't work with CAS

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, logout, cas

I'm triying to make a simple pre logout hook, i have my main class CustomPreLogoutAction.java, my portal.properties in the same package with

```
logout.events.pre=CustomPreLogoutAction
```

and the liferay-hook.xml with these lines:

```
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
</hook>
```

I did a simple hook for the login and it works fine, but in the Logout it did't work, i tried logout.events.pre, logout.events.post but they don't work.
The problem is that liferay don't use the default logout cause CAS is implemented.

(insert the methods in CentralAuthenticationService.deleteTicketGrantingTicket() can be a solution, but i want to make a hook) How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's working properly. Please specify the full path to your class like

```
logout.events.pre=com.abhishek.CustomPreLogoutAction
```

and extend your class with `Action`.

Comment: Tried but doesn't work, when i dissable the CAS works, but with CAS active not